# D3 Update, Enter, Exit pattern

Tags: d3.js

I am new to D3, however have been practicing with it.  I am having a problem with the Update, Enter and Exit pattern.  Here is some code I have been testing.

```js
function myFunction(myData){
    let width = 10;
    let height = 10;

    console.log('Update: ',m.selectAll('rect')
    .data(myData, d => d.Value).size());

    d3.select('g').selectAll('rect')
        .data(myData, d=> d.Value)
        .attr('width', d => d.Value);

    console.log('Enter: ' + m.selectAll('rect')
        .data(myData, d => d.Value)
        .enter()
        .size()
    );
    d3.select('g').selectAll('rect')
        .data(myData, d => d.Value)
        .enter()
            .append('rect')
                .attr('width',function(d){return d.Value;})
                .attr('height', height)
                .attr('y', (d,i) => i * 50);
    console.log('Exit: ' + d3.select('g').selectAll('rect')
        .data(myData, d => d.Value)
            .exit().size());

    d3.select('g').selectAll('rect')
        .data(myData, d => d.Value)
            .exit().remove();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My Chart</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="superChart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="padding: 10px;">
    <button onclick="myFunction(myData)">Refresh!</button>
    <button onclick="myFunction(myData.filter(d => d.Title == 'Cat'))">Cat!</button>
    <button onclick="myFunction(myData.filter(d => d.Title == 'Dog'))">Dog!</button>
    <button onclick="myFunction(myData.filter(d => d.Title == 'Rat'))">Rat!</button>
    <button onclick="myFunction(myData.filter(d => d.Title == 'Bat'))">Bat!</button>
    <button onclick="myFunction(myData.filter(d => d.Title == 'Gnat'))">Gnat!</button>
    <button onclick="myFunction(myData.filter(d => d.Title == 'Mat'))">Mat!</button>
</div>
<div class="visual"></div>


    <script>
        var myData = [
            {Title:'Cat',Value:56},
            {Title:'Dog',Value:78},
            {Title:'Rat',Value:45},
            {Title:'Bat',Value:30},
            {Title:'Gnat',Value:19},
            {Title:'Mat',Value:37}

        ]
        var m = d3.select('.visual')
        .append('svg')
            .attr('width','700')
            .attr('height','400')
            .append('g');
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the code and click on different filter buttons.  I noticed that the enter selection is run each time a different button is selected.  From what I understand, the enter selection should run when there is more data than DOM elements.  In all but one case (the Refresh button) only one rect is in the DOM so shouldn't the update selection apply?

For example, clicking "Cat!" causes the enter selection as expected.  Then clicking "Dog!" triggers the enter and exit selection.  Since the newly filtered data has only one datum and there is only one rect, I would expect the update selection to be triggered.  What am I missing?

Comment: every time you call `.data` it binds data and influences the next `.data` call

Comment: @rioV8  Wow. That made all the difference!  I just assigned .data to a variable and now everything works as expected.  If you want to post an answer. I will mark it as answered.  I didn't know that binding data affected subsequent bindings.  Thank you!

Comment: it changes the bound data so IT will change the next data binding, how else do you think it works

Comment: I really don't know exactly how it works.  I have been reading about D3 in general.  Must of missed that important detail.  I still have much to learn.

Comment: Really what I thought that .data did was to create a mapping with the data and the DOM elements, bucketing them in .enter, .exit and .group. It sounds like there is more to it than that.

Comment: I take it back...it is now not working again.  This behavior is strange.  If you look at my array above, you will notice that each of the names in the objects are capitalized, "Title" and "Value". You will also notice that in myFunction above access the members via d.Value.  However only when I do a data join using d.value (lower case "v") does it update the rects.  If i capitalize the "V" to match the name in the object...it only enters....I am confused again...

Comment: the rect changes size so `d.Value` is correct. Only do the data binding **ONCE**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here.

1. Thanks to rioV8 for pointing out that I should not bind data multiple times as it effects subsequent data binds.
2. The way I bound the data.  For example, below is how I bound my data.

`d3.select('g').selectAll('rect')
        .data(myData, d => d.Value);`

The anonymous function here is not necessary and was causing strange behavior.  When I change my data binding to this...

```
d3.select('g').selectAll('rect')
    .data(myData);
```

Everything works as expected.

@rioV8 Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Please accept the answer (even if it is your own) if it solves the problem.